# Primefaces DataTable - override onRowClick

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I would like to ovveride the the onRowClick function for a specific DataTable. I have already done it with a tree and it's working. In this case the selection is broken and I don't see the reason.

Here my simple code:

```
PF('myTableWidget').onRowClick = function (event, rowElement, silent) {
    //do some stuff
    PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.onRowClick.call(event, rowElement, silent);
};
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to just override a single widget, not the general implementation. I have found my problem, I answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to put "this" as first parameter in the prototype method call

```
PF('myTableWidget').onRowClick = function (event, rowElement, silent) {
    //do some stuff
    PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.onRowClick.call(this,event, rowElement, silent);
};
```